# Iterating a vector over the rows of a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a relatively basic question.

I have a matrix with 20 columns and 50 rows.
I have a vector of 20 numbers.

I want to multiply the vector over each row of the matrix such that each row builds on the values of the previous row (i.e. row[n]<-row[n-1]*1.5).

I assume using a for-loop is how I want to do this, but I can't seem to figure out the right command to get R to do it.  So far it gives me warnings that the "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" and only carries out the operation over the first column of the matrix.

Example code:

```
trun<-50
prun<-20
M<-matrix(0,trun,prun)
M[1,]<-10
v<-seq(0.05,1,by=0.05)
for (t in 2:trun)
{
M[t]<-M[t-1]*v
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Your vector `v` has length of 20 while your column vector  has length of 50. So, R gives a warning; in this case R recycles.

Comment: To refer to row `t`, use `M[t,]` instead of `M[t]`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the mtcars data for the solution:(You can avoid using R `for loop` for your problem; I use `map` below for that)

```
    mydata<-mtcars[1:10,1:4]
    mydata<-as.matrix(mydata)
> mydata
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123

    myvec<-seq(1,8,1)
   kk<-ldply(Map(function(x) myout=myvec*mydata[(2:dim(mydata)[1]),x], as.list(colnames(mydata)))) # applying over over all columns. 
library(plyr)
myout<-t(ldply(kk))



                       [,1] [,2]   [,3] [,4]
Mazda RX4          21.0    6  160.0  110
Mazda RX4 Wag      42.0   12  320.0  220
Datsun 710         68.4   12  324.0  279
Hornet 4 Drive     85.6   24 1032.0  440
Hornet Sportabout  93.5   40 1800.0  875
Valiant           108.6   36 1350.0  630
Duster 360        100.1   56 2520.0 1715
Merc 240D         195.2   32 1173.6  496
Merc 230           22.8    4  140.8   95
Merc 280           38.4   12  335.2  246
```

Note: Since the length of vec is only 8, only the first 8 element (excluding first row) of each column is transformed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think this does what you want, first using a `for-loop` and then using `apply`.  Both approaches give the same answer:

```
set.seed(1234)

nrow <- 5
ncol <- 7

M <- matrix(floor(runif(nrow*ncol, 0, 10)), ncol = ncol, byrow=TRUE)
M <- as.data.frame(M)
M
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
# 1  1  6  6  6  8  6  0
# 2  2  6  5  6  5  2  9
# 3  2  8  2  2  1  2  3
# 4  3  1  0  2  8  5  9
# 5  8  0  4  2  3  5  1

v <- seq(1, 5, by = (5-1) / (ncol-1))
v
# [1] 1.000000 1.666667 2.333333 3.000000 3.666667 4.333333 5.000000

for (t in 2:nrow(M))
   {
     M[t,] <- M[t-1,] * v
   }
M

M.bottom <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(seq(2,nrow(M)), function(i) { apply(M[i-1,], 1, function(x) x * v) })))

new.M <- rbind(M[1,], M.bottom)
new.M

#   V1       V2        V3  V4         V5        V6 V7
# 1  1  6.00000   6.00000   6    8.00000    6.0000  0
# 2  1 10.00000  14.00000  18   29.33333   26.0000  0
# 3  1 16.66667  32.66667  54  107.55556  112.6667  0
# 4  1 27.77778  76.22222 162  394.37037  488.2222  0
# 5  1 46.29630 177.85185 486 1446.02469 2115.6296  0
```